# PHP file in wordpress generating json file for fusioncharts

Tags: php, json, wordpress, fusioncharts

In WordPress, I have a FusionCharts `div` in a page called "JSON" that points to a file called `jsontest.php`. `jsontest.php` contains the following code that generates a JSON file.

```
<?php

$result=mysql_query ("SELECT date, last_close_eur FROM pricing limit 10");

$i=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $response[$i]['DATE']  = $row['DATE']; 
    $response[$i]['LAST_CLOSE_EUR']= $row['LAST_CLOSE_EUR'];
    $data['posts'][$i] = $response[$i];
   $i=$i+1;
} 

$json_string = json_encode($data);

$file = 'file.json';
file_put_contents($file, $json_string); 
?>
```

Output file does not contain any data. Any idea?

Comment: This is normally a permissions issue, where PHP cannot write to the directory. What do you get if you do: var_dump(file_put_contents($file, $json_string)); Also you may want to check that the json is being created properly by doing var_dump($json_string);

Comment: thanks jd182, pls see Hindmost reply below... still no data tho so have kept it open... query works fine in phpmyadmin, but data not generated in the file...

Comment: Even if the query is working in phpMyAdmin you need to check that all the variables are as expected in your code. I'd start with the following: var_dump($data); var_dump($json_string); The first one should be your array, the second should be a json string. Are they both correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
$file = dirname(__FILE__). '/file.json';
file_put_contents($file, $json_string);
```

Comment: Thanks Hindmost, does indeed work, problem was actually that somehow parentheses got lost after "$result=mysql_query..."... have put them in and bingo... but still no data in the file...